# TicTacToe Loop fix

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a tic-tac-toe game that will (eventually) have the user play against the computer. For right now, I need to figure out how to get it to loop. How can I do this?

So far, it will print the board and where the user wants to place 1 'x', then ends the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    Scanner keyboard;
    String[] temp;
    String xTemp, yTemp;
    int x,y;
    char [][] board = new char [3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 3;k++){
            board [i][k] = ' ';
        }
    }

    do{
        //Asking for new move.
        printBoard(board);
        System.out.println("Input coordinates to begin the game. ex: (1,2): ");
        System.out.println("Please include parenthesis and comma.");
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        //Splitting input into coordinates
        temp = input.split(",");
        //Setting coordinates
        xTemp = temp[0].replace("(", "");
        yTemp = temp[1].replace(")", "");
        //Convert xy(temp) Strings to Ints
        x = Integer.parseInt(xTemp);
        y = Integer.parseInt(yTemp);
      }
    while (!checkMove(x,y));

    board[x][y] = 'X';

    printBoard(board);

    } 

    //Checking for parameters
    public static boolean checkMove(int x, int y){
      if (x > 2 || x < 0){
            System.out.println("Input an X move between 0 & 2");
        }
      if (y > 2 || y < 0){
            System.out.println("Input a Y move between 0 & 2");  
        }
      if (x > 2 || x < 0 || y > 2 || y < 0){
          return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;
      }

      }

      public static void printBoard(char[][] board){
        System.out.println("  0 1 2");
        System.out.println("0|" + board[0][0] + "|" + board[1][0] + "|" + board[2][0] + "|");
        System.out.println(" -------");
        System.out.println("1|" + board[0][1] + "|" + board[1][1] + "|" + board[2][1] + "|");
        System.out.println(" -------");
        System.out.println("2|" + board[0][2] + "|" + board[1][2] + "|" + board[2][2] + "|");
      }
}
```

Comment: it's a game... games tend to have ends, meaning there's a winning/losing condition. your code doesn't check for that at all. you just keep asking for moves (without checking if that move is even valid). `[1][1] = 'x'` followed by `[1][1] = 'o'` would lead to fights between players...

Answer (score 0):

Without telling you you should completely re-tool or spoiling the fun by giving a complete tic-tac-toe solution...

I think you'll find the snippet below gives you just enough to progress your little programming experiment.

```
do {

    do {


        // Print board and get move input...

    } while (!checkMove(board, x, y)); // gotta pass the board to this function for the reasons Marc B mentioned

    board[x][y] = 'X';

} while (!gameOver(board));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simplify your board representation and entry method as such:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String board = "123\n456\n789\n";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String move;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(board + "Enter a move (ie x3):");
            move = input.nextLine();
            if (move.equals(""))
                break;
            board = board.replace(move.substring(1,2), move.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```

You can add more logic if you want it to automatically alternate turns for X and O.

Answer (score 0):

```
if value of x=1 then you are returning 'true' and so do while loop terminates. You need to change if condition as:-

public static boolean checkMove(int x, int y){
  if (x > 0 || x < 2){
        System.out.println("Input an X move between 0 & 2");
    }
  if (y > 0 || y < 2){
        System.out.println("Input a Y move between 0 & 2");  
    }
  if (x > 0 || x < 2 || y > 0 || y < 2){
      return false;
  }
  else {
      return true;
  }

  }
```